# Why does FFMpeg stop after five seconds when run from a Perl daemon?

Tags: perl, ffmpeg

I wrote a little daemon in Perl that calls up FFMpeg to encode a video but the encoding stops after 5 or so seconds.

I use this piece of code to start it:

```
my $t = `echo '$ffmpeg_command' >>$self->{FFMPEG_OUTPUT}`;
my $log_data = `$ffmpeg_command 2>>$self->{FFMPEG_OUTPUT}`;
```

Any ideas?

If I start the FFMpeg command myself it works fine by the way.

Comment: What does `$ffmpeg_command` look like? I suspect a simple I/O deadlock, but I can only guess if I don't know where ffmpeg is getting its data from or where it's sending it to :)

Comment: The command I use is
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /data/media/mymedia.ts -y -threads 0 -crf 22 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -ab 128k -vpre hq /data/encoded/test.m4v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself

It was an IO lock, apparently you will have to add `</dev/null` at the end of the command

My above statement will look like this:

```
my $log_data = `$ffmpeg_command 2>>$self->{FFMPEG_OUTPUT} </dev/null`;
```